# How do I make my python socket server available to the world?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip, client-server

So I have just finished working on a python online game, using python sockets module and pygame, and want to make it available to my friends to play.

The problem is with the IP address of my router - it seems to have an IP of the form 10.x.x.x, which is apparently a private IP address, and so I cannot connect a client to it.

My ISP is probably using NAT, and hence port-forwarding just my router wouldn’t solve the issue.

Please let me know if there is a way I can have my friends connect to the socket server hosted on my computer, from outside my LAN. Preferably for free.

TIA

Comment: This is a router-specific problem.  You need to find how to configure your router so that some public port, say 1234, is mapped to the specific port on your local machine on which your server is running.  You also need to find out the public address of your router by typing 'whats my ip to Google.  Your friends can then access your service using your router's world-facing IP, and the port you are forwarding

Comment: @FrankYellin if you are talking about port forwarding, I have already tried that.
The problem is my router’s IP isn’t really public, it is a private IP assigned by my ISP, that connects to the internet after going through a NAT.
I have concluded the above by typing what’s my IP in google and verifying that it returns an IP address that it is different from what is displayed in my routers settings.

Comment: In any case.  Your question is about your ISP and your router box, not about Python.